# Method visible everywhere in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, logging

How can I make this method, which outputs a yellow line in the log file, accessible from everywhere (Models, Controllers, Views) in my Rails app?

```
def my_log(text, file = "", line = "")
  text.to_s.chomp.gsub!(/%/, "%%")
  Rails.logger.debug(sprintf("\033[32m#{file}#{line}\033[0m\033[1m\033[33m#{text}\033[0m"))
end
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could define it in `Kernel` (NOT recommended):

```
module Kernel
  def my_log(..)
    ..
  end
end
```

... if you *really* want it available anywhere.

Or, place something like this in `lib/util.rb`:

```
module Util
  def self.my_log(..)
    ..
  end
end
```

... and make sure to `require 'util'` in your `config/application.rb` and then you can call this anywhere:

```
Util.my_log(..)
```

Comment: I am getting the error: `application.rb:3:in 'require': no such file to load -- util (LoadError)`. I tried also `require 'lib/util'` but no luck.

Comment: @Luke - i) are you using Rails 2 or 3; ii) where is your util.rb file exactly; iii) where did you put the line `require 'util'`?

Comment: i) Rails 3; ii) Under my_app/lib; iii) At the top of the file, after "require 'rails/all'"

Comment: For iii), at the top of *which* file exactly?

Comment: OK, that's probably why it doesn't work. Try adding it in a new file under `config/initializers`.

Answer (score 7):

why not create an initializer and write this method to the rails module?

```
# config/initializers.rb
module Rails

  def self.log_with_colour(message, level = :debug)
    text.to_s.chomp.gsub!(/%/, "%%")
    logger.send(level, sprintf("\033[32m#{__FILE__}#{__LINE__}\033[0m\033[1m\033[33m#{message}\033[0m"))
  end

end
```

in your code you can then call `Rails.log_with_colour("hello")` or `Rails.log_with_colour("Hello again", :info)`

Comment: If you're using it throughout your app, this is the better way to do it (initializers are automatically loaded so no need to require).

Comment: Sounds good. Is the `Rails` module mandatory? Something like `module Logger [..] end` wouldn't work?

Comment: That would work. You'd have to include that module in every place that you want to use the logger methods though. Also - there's already a class named Logger, so there would be name clash

Answer (score 3):

I put stuff like this in `config/initializers/app_methods.rb`.  They don't need to be scoped inside a class or module.  Feels a bit hacky but i never had any problems.

Answer (score 2):

Add it as an instance and class method in Object

```
class Object
  def self.my_log(...)
    ...
  end

  def my_log(...)
    Object.my_log(...)
  end
end
```