# Rails 4: where to place Struct?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

Where should I put a simple Struct so that every model/controller would be able to use it?

`Errors = Struct.new(:file_name, :errors)`

Right now I'm just defining this structure in every model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to place it anywhere in your load paths and the file needs to be named 'errors.rb'. Best place probably would be within `lib`, assuming you have added it to your load_paths in your `config/application.rb`:

```
config.autoload_paths << config.root.join('lib')
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want a new class definition to be available in any scope (models, controllers, views) you should place it into the `lib/` folder.

This answer might help you:

[Method visible everywhere in Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6227772/method-visible-everywhere-in-rails)